# Flutter - Could not find the correct Provider

Tags: flutter

I've got an app having file structure like this: main -> auth -> home -> secret. Key codes are as below:

For `main.dart`:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>.value(value: AuthService().user),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SecretProvider()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My Secrets',
        home: AuthScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For `home.dart`:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var secretProvider = Provider.of<SecretProvider>(context);

    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => SecretProvider(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          // some codes...
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<List<Secret>>(
          stream: secretProvider.secrets,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
              child: ListView.separated(
                // return 0 if snapshot.data is null
                itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.web),
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].title),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.edit),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => SecretScreen(
                            secret: snapshot.data[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Divider();
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecretScreen()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For `secret.dart`:

```
class SecretScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Secret secret;

  SecretScreen({this.secret});

  @override
  _SecretScreenState createState() => _SecretScreenState();
}

class _SecretScreenState extends State<SecretScreen> {
  // some codes...

  @override
  void initState() {
    final secretProvider = Provider.of<SecretProvider>(context, listen: false);

    // some codes...

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // some codes...

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final secretProvider = Provider.of<SecretProvider>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      // some codes...
    );
  }
}
```

These codes worked just fine, but later on I decided to move the `ChangeNotifierProvider` from `main.dart` to `home.dart` due to some class instance life cycle issue. The new code is like below:

For `main.dart`:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>.value(value: AuthService().user),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My Secrets',
        home: AuthScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For `home.dart`:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // var secretProvider = Provider.of<SecretProvider>(context);

    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => SecretProvider(),
      child: Consumer<SecretProvider>(
        builder: (context, secretProvider, child) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              // some codes...
            ),
            body: StreamBuilder<List<Secret>>(
              stream: secretProvider.secrets,
              // stream: SecretProvider().secrets,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
                  child: ListView.separated(
                    // return 0 if snapshot.data is null
                    itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.web),
                        title: Text(snapshot.data[index].title),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.edit),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => SecretScreen(
                                secret: snapshot.data[index],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Divider();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecretScreen()),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Basically, I just moved the `ChangeNotifierProvider` to `home.dart` and used a `Consumer` to pass the context, but this time, whenever I navigate to `secret` screen, it prompts me error like below:

```
Could not find the correct Provider<SecretProvider> above this SecretScreen Widget

This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.
```

This `BuildContext` is really bugging me. Even if I'm having `ChangeNotifierProvider` one level lower than before, the `SecretScreen` widget should still be aware of the `SecretProvider` that passed on from `HomeScreen` because it's still the child of `HomeScreen` and according to my knowledge, the context should contain the `SecretProvider`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because your `SecretProvider` instance is part of `HomeScreen` which is not a parent of `SecretScreen`.

In order, when you push a new page, this new page is not a descendent of the previous one so you can't access to inherited object with the `.of(context)` method.

Here the a schema representing the widget tree to explain the situation :

1. With a Provider on top of MaterialApp (the navigator)  :

   ```
   Provider
     MaterialApp
       HomeScreen -> push SecretScreen
       SecretScreen -> Here we can acces the Provider by calling Provider.of(context) because the context can access to its ancestors
   ```
2. With a Provider created in HomeScreen :

   ```
   MaterialApp
     HomeScreen -> push SecretScreen
       Provider -> The provider is part of HomeScreen
     SecretScreen -> The context can't access to the Provider because it's not part of its ancestors
   ```

I hope my answer is pretty clear and will help you to understand what happens ;)

Comment: Nice explanation, could you also write some code inside the answer for the community, Thanks

Comment: @jitsm555 done :) Tell me if that adds more clarity ;)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I always think that the pushed page is the child of the previous one. But if I do want to make this code work without moving the provider to a sort of parent of the HomeScreen, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What you did in first place is the thing to do. Providers are intended to be used like this. You can still pass objects to your pages but you loose the benefits of Providers

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.